# _chalk.default.constructor is not a constructor in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am new to next  Next.js. I am getting error,I tried to change next.config for webpack ,still error.

After adding ***getServerSideProps*** in Index.jsx error start to appear.

```
TypeError: _chalk.default.constructor is not a constructor
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jai shankar\Desktop\RSS\React\Next\fbclone-yt\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\plugins\wellknown-errors-plugin\parseBabel.js:1:277)

at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jai shankar\Desktop\RSS\React\Next\fbclone-yt\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\plugins\wellknown-errors-plugin\webpackModuleError.js:1:174)
```

Below is Index.js file

```js
import Head from "next/head";
// import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css'
import React from "react";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import Login from "../components/Login";

export default function Home({ session }) {
  if (!session) return <Login />;

  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Facebook clone</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      {/* Header */}
      <Header />
      <main>
        {/* sidebar */}

        {/* fees */}

        {/* Widget */}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const session = await getSession(context);
  return {
    props: {
      session,
    },
  };
}
```

below is next. config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  // reactStrictMode: true,
  webpack5: true,
  images: {
    domains: [
      "http://localhost:3000/",
      "m.media-amazon.com",
      "links.papareact.com",
      "platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com",
      "firebasestorage.googleapis.com",
      "facebookbrand.com",
      "pbs.twimg.com",
    ],
  },
};
```

Git repo- [Git repository](https://github.com/Jhaamlal/Next-js)

Comment: Where does `getSession` come from?

Comment: @juliomalves its probably `next-auth` :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into a similar error message. To fix:

I deleted `node_modules` and npm installed again and things started working again.

Comment: Thanks, I did this same.